# Creating a column chart from dictionary values in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create a column chart from values that I have stored in a dictionary (Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")) in VBA. The x-axis are the keys and the y axis are the values. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub WriteDictionary()

    Dim dict As Variant
    Dim currRow As Integer


    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    currRow = 1

    dict.Add "key 1", "data 1"
    dict.Add "key 2", "data 2"

    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        Range("A" & currRow).Formula = Key
        Range("B" & currRow).Formula = dict(Key)
        currRow = currRow + 1
    Next Key

    Set dict = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this question because I had the same question, and I didn't find the answer here.

I'm using arrays to store the data from the scripting dictionary. Then, the arrays provide the source data for the graph.

```
Sub DictToChart()

    'Arrays for graph
    Dim xinput As Variant
    Dim yinput As Variant

    'Example dictionary
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    'Populate dictionary
    dict.Add 0, 0
    dict.Add 10, 1
    dict.Add 20, 2
    dict.Add 30, 3
    dict.Add 40, 4

    'Populate arrays for graph
    ReDim xinput(0 To dict.Count - 1)
    ReDim yinput(0 To dict.Count - 1)

    For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
        xinput(i) = dict.Keys(i)
        yinput(i) = dict.Items(i)
    Next i

    'Create graph
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

    With ActiveChart
        .SeriesCollection(1).xvalues = xinput
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = yinput
    End With


End Sub
```